# Improving the below RegEx for US and UK Names

Tags: regex, validation, alphanumeric

I'm looking to validate English names. How could I improve this RegEx in order to ensure that the hyphen, comma or apostrophe does not come first or last in the string? Further, a hyphen or apostrophe must always be directly preceded and succeeded with a letter.

I have the RegEx: `[a-zA-Z-', ]`.

My understanding is that this will allow for all letters, in all cases, hyphens, commas and apostrophes along with whitespace at any location in the string.

Quite new to the language so just getting my head around it.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the function know it's being given a name, or can it be something else and have to determine if it's a name?

Comment: It expects a name

Comment: Why has this been downvoted, it seems like a reasonable question?

Comment: Some people here don't like beginners, and they downvote them without even telling them if they're doing something wrong, or what they consider to be too simple to be asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since it's only given a presumed name, here's what you might want to try:

```
^[A-Z][A-Za-z'-]+[a-z](,? [A-Z][A-Za-z'-]+[a-z])*$
```

This will work with names like `O'Harry` `Jefferson-Wayne`, but will reject words not ending with a small English letter.

The gist of it is this `[A-Z]` start of name, `[A-Za-z'-]+` continuation, `[a-z]` end of name. then a repeatable group of optional names, with an optional comma delimiter, but required space.

I took more time writing the examples to test at http://www.regexplanet.com/. That's where I practice my regular expressions when I'm developing. You should try it.